# control systems

Tags: matlab

How can I solve the following problem?

> Let G(s)=1/500s2 and H(s)= (s+1)/(s+2). Obtain M(s)=[G(s)]/[1-G(s)H(s)] without using symbolic toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [Control System Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/control/) is available to you, you can do it this way:

```
G = tf(1,[500 0 0]) % create the transfer function object for G
H = tf([1 1],[1 2]) % create the transfer function object for H
M = feedback(G,H,1) % calculate [G(s)]/[1-G(s)H(s)]
[num,den]= tfdata(M) % obtain the cell arrays with numerator and denominator coefficients
```

Comment: [it calculates](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/feedback.html) the transfer function object for the closed loop system. This function equals to [G(s)]/[1-G(s)H(s)] (in the case of positive feedback)